# tern.js not loading three.js plugin

Tags: javascript, three.js, neovim, youcompleteme, tern

## Problem

I'm currently trying to build a 3D web app based on `three.js`.

I'm using [`neovim`](https://neovim.io) as my development environment and [`YouCompleteMe`](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/) as a completion system.

I installed tern to complete JS, and I added `.tern-project` file like this.

```
{
    "libs": [
        "browser",
        "ecmascript",
    ],
    "loadEagerly": [
    ],
    "plugins": {
        "threejs": {}
    }
}
```

I also copied `threejs.js` and `threejs.json` to my project's directory generated by [tern-threejs](https://github.com/tylerwbell/tern-threejs).

However, YouCompleteMe doesn't show semantic completion compared to [tern-threejs's demo codemirror](http://demo-angelozerr.rhcloud.com/CodeMirror-Java/threejs.html)

## Comparison:

codemirror:

[image: codemirror]

neovim:

[image: neovim]

Note: I can't see any completion at all.

What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

`threejs.js` is a tern **plugin** file and `threejs.json` is a tern **library** file. plugin files should be copied in `tern/plugin` directory and library files needs to be placed within `tern/defs` directory. These two directory exists within tern directory.

With 'YouCompleteMe' installed this dir path is: `~/.vim/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/tern-runtime/node‌​_modules/tern`. You only need to copy one of aforementioned files. Plugin file or lib file; and update your `.tern-project` file accordingly. so:

1. First ensure that you have enabled the Tern completer on YouCompleteMe. For example on my Mac, I had to run the following:

   ```
   cd ~/.vim/bundle/YouCompleteMe
   ./install.py --tern-completer
   ```

   See YouCompleteMe [installation guide](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe#installation) for details on how to do it on other environments.
2. Copy `threejs.js` then navigate to

   ```
   ~/.vim/YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/tern-runtime/node‌​_modules/tern/plugin/
   ```

   and paste.
3. Update your project's `.tern-project` file as follows:

   ```
   {
       "libs": [
           "browser",
           "ecmascript",
       ],
       "plugins": {
           "es_modules": {},
           "threejs": {}
       }
   }
   ```

   **Note** that i've also included `es_modules` plugin (which is a plugin shipped with tern itself) as you are using ES6 module pattern system.

Comment: Well, it didn't work. For starters, there was no such directory like `YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/tern`. I managed to find `YouCompleteMe/third_party/ycmd/third_party/tern-runtime/node_modules/tern`, so I copied `threejs.js` to `plugin` directory, but It didn't work.

Comment: The problem persists even though I run `./install.py` with `--tern-completer`.

Comment: @sohnryang, Your tern path is correct; so i updated the answer. By the way did you also copied `.tern-project` file into your project directory. All your `.js` files should be placed within or with the descendants of the directory where `.tern-project` has been placed.

Comment: I already updated `.tern-project` file, but I can't see any completion.